# Неправильная сериализация словаря python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, telebot

Доброго времени суток!

Делаю бота, который должен записывать данные по юзеру в json. Накидал такой код. Он пробует прочитать файл json, и если он пустой, то создает новый словарь со значениями первого пользователя, после чего сохраняет в файл.

```py
#регистрация в json
with open('users/user_progres.json', 'r+') as progress:

  try:
    users_steps = json.load(progress)
    print(users_steps)
    print('Прочитал ****************************')
    
  except:
    users_steps = {}
    print('Создал ****************************')
    
  users_steps[user_id] = {'user_code': str(message.text), 'user_cur_step': '0'}
  print(users_steps)
  print('Записал ************************')
  json.dump(users_steps, progress, indent=2)
  progress.close()
```

После первого запуска я имею следующую запись в файле

```
{
  "123123": {
    "user_code": "some_code",
    "user_cur_step": "0"
  }
}
```

После второго запись меняется на следующую

```
{
  "123123": {
    "user_code": "some_code",
    "user_cur_step": "0"
  }
}{
  "123123": {
    "user_code": "some_code",
    "user_cur_step": "0"
  },
  "123123": {
    "user_code": "some_code",
    "user_cur_step": "0"
  }
}
```

Мало того, что добавляется два значения, так еще и становится понятно, что только второй объект является цельным словарем, после первого нет запятой. После третьего и всех последующих запусков опять добавляются элементы, как первый, то есть с разделением не запятой, а создается как бы отдельный словарь.
Прошу помочь разобраться, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Во-первых, вы после чтения не перемотали файл обратно в начало через seek, и в итоге файловый курсор остался в конце файла — вот всё в конец и пишется. Во-вторых, даже если вы перемотаете его в начало, вы выполните запись поверх старых данных — и если новые данные короче чем старые, то в конце останется торчать кусок старых данных, который вам нужно будет отрезать с помощью truncate

Comment: @andreymal, а почему у него во втором объекте ключ 123123 встречается дважды?

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что коряво заменил реальные данные перед публикацией вопроса?

Comment: @andreymal, возможно. Но мне кажется, я раньше встречал похожий вопрос про одинаковые ключи...

Comment: @andreymal Ключ там пишется одинаковый, это id моего чата с ботом. Сделал по вашему комментарию, спасибо! Теперь после второго запуска добавляется одна запись, а после всех последующих - не добавляется новых строк, то есть ограничение словаря почему-то не срабатывает сразу

Comment: А да, тогда другое объяснение — json не может хранить ключи-числа и во время записи преобразовывает их в строки, вы читаете json-файл, получаете ключ-строку и ещё добавляете ключ-число — в итоге в файле получается два одинаковых ключа

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо большущее! Теперь все заработало. Вы просто спасли этот вечер))

Comment: Ну и всё это уже неоднократно обсуждалось и можно поискать похожие вопросы например [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1437097) или [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1005005) (но прям совсем идентичных дубликатов беглым взглядом не видно)